# Temporarily generate Office Document using Template and Lists from the SP library (SP2010 Foundation)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document-template, bulk

We use SharePoint Foundation 2010 Server for planing IT courses, where we have different lists for participants and for different courses.
We also have all course certificates in one library.
What we want is to quickly generate multiple certificates with participant names and other data (course title, dates etc.) from the existing lists. These freshly generated documents should not be in anyway persisted on the server, but just sent to the participants per mail or printed.
How can we reach this type of automation in SharePoint Foundation?

Comment: You may be able to accomplish that using infopath 2010 and workflows. Have you looked into that?

Comment: Can I use InfoPath 2010 with SP Foundations? I thought I need an Enterprise SP for this. Besides, I want to stick to existing Word and Excel templates (if that is possible).

Comment: Whoops. Let me retag your question.